# R programming ifelse() programming

Tags: r

I have a dataset named `malt`, where one of the columns is named `ka`. I want to replace `NA` values in that `ka` column by mean values in `malt$ka` and other value remain as it is, so do this by if else

```
 malt$ka <- ifelse(malt$ka=="NA", mean(malt$ka), "malt$AcqCostPercust")
```

This does not seem to work, and I am confused how to replace values the `NA` values.

Comment: try `ifelse(is.na(malt$ka),mean(malt$ka,na.rm = TRUE),malt$AcqCostPercust)`

Comment: @Batanichek don't forget to have `na.rm = T` in `mean`

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
malt$ka[is.na(malt$ka)] <- mean(malt$ka, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- mean(malt$ka, na.rm=T) # assign mean value to a variable x
malt$ka<-ifelse(is.na(malt$ka),x,malt$ka)
```